# serialport.write() in c# is working when debugging but not when debug point is removed and run

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm working on a project in which I'm writing "Y" and "N" signals to a serial port, this is working fine when I debug but when a break point is removed and run, it's not writing "Y" or "N" signals. Strange problem. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Note:I am using visual studio 2010,windows forms with c#

Code:

```
if(balance>25)
   serialport.Write("Y");
else
    serialport.Write("N");
```

Comment: How do you know that your code gets called and that nothing is written to the serial port?

Comment: There is not enough information to help you solve this. This is most likely a timing issue, where using the debugger will give *something* enough time to flush, react, process, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

When using serial ports, you have to close or flush the stream. When you debug you see values inside the stream, but when you run if you haven't close or flush stream it will not write.

Just try to close or flush stream

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply.. you mean to say i have to close and open serial port again ? I am not using any stream here so... I am completely new to this pls bear with me..